# Can lambda() that never evaluates to a constant expression be a `constexpr`-function in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, constexpr

Lambda's `operator()` is implicitly `constexpr` according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

> When this specifier (`constexpr`) is not present, the function call operator or any given operator template specialization will be `constexpr` anyway, if it happens to satisfy all `constexpr` function requirements

And a requirement of a `constexpr`-function according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

> there exists at least one set of argument values such that an invocation of the function could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (for constructors, use in a constant initializer is sufficient) (since C++14). No diagnostic is required for a violation of this bullet.

In the next example, the function `t()` always throws an exception by calling lambda `l()`:

```
auto l = []()->bool { throw 42; };
constexpr bool t() { return l(); }
```

GCC rejects this function with the error:

```
call to non-'constexpr' function '<lambda()>'
```

but Clang accepts the program (until the function `t()` is used in a constant evaluation), meaning that it considers `l()` a `constexpr`-function, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/j1z7ee3Wv

Is it a bug in Clang, or such compiler behavior is also acceptable?

Comment: As your quote states: **No diagnostic is required for a violation of this bullet.**

Comment: No diagnostic required doesn't really seem to answer the question. The declaration is well-formed. Can the compiler implicitly mark such a call operator as constexpr? By the text, it must be marked non-constexpr, but it's difficult to implement that. Is the difference even observable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All three compilers do issue an error when you actually try to use the result of `t()` in a context that requires a constant expression. [For example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fojoE7G9e):

```
auto l = []()->bool { throw 42; };
constexpr bool t() { return l(); }

template <bool x>
struct dummy {};

int main() {
   dummy< t() > d;   // error: t() is not a constant expression
}
```

As mentioned in a comment by NathanOliver, your quote already states:

> [...] No diagnostic is required for a violation of this bullet.

Compilers need not necessarily proove that there is no set of argument values that allow the function to return a constant expression. On the other hand, a compiler can easily verify for a given argument value, that the result is not a constant expression.