# constexpr constructor which may never be constexpr instantiated

Tags: c++, constexpr

I have come across a case of `constexpr` usage where I don't understand why the code compiles. Here is a [minimal and reproducible example](https://godbolt.org/z/zdWdYMvv5) (Godbolt):

```cpp
struct A
{
    A(int a_)
    :m_a{a_}
    {
    }

    int m_a;
};

// Compilation fails with this structure:
struct B
{
    constexpr B(A a_)
    :m_a{a_}
    {
    }

    A m_a;
};

// Compilation OK here, even if A is not constexpr.
struct BOK
{
    constexpr BOK(const A& a_)
    :m_a{a_}
    {
    }

    A m_a;
};

int main()
{
    // constexpr A a{2};          // Fails. OK, A's constructor is not constexpr
    // constexpr B b{A(2)};       // Fails. OK, A's constructor is not constexpr
    // constexpr BOK bok{A(2)};   // Fails. OK, A's constructor is not constexpr

    const BOK bok{A(2)};

    return 0;
}
```

I understand that `B` does not compile and the error is clear:

```
error: invalid type for parameter 1 of 'constexpr' function 'constexpr B::B(A)'
```

What I don't understand if why `BOK` does compile (especially since `B` doesn't). It seems the `const&` somehow makes it OK for the compiler. As I am showing in the `main` function, trying to instantiate a `constexpr` version of `BOK` fails to compile with error:

```
error: the type 'const BOK' of 'constexpr' variable 'bok' is not literal
```

as expected, but the struct's definition seems to be fine. It is weird because is seems the compiler thinks there might be a possibility for this to be `constexpr`... Is there? Why does this work?

I have tried this with both `g++` and `clang` with the `-std=c++20` switch.

Comment: Standard does not require the compiler to analyze function body for constexpr correctnesson definition. There are quite a few such questions with explanations here searchable by `constexpr no diagnostic required`, e.g. [What does decl.constexpr.5 mean exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62327672/4074081), [Can lambda that never evaluates to a constant expression be a constexpr-function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69616430/4074081).

Comment: You were right; sorry: I've compiled a different code. Answer wrong and deleted. I don't know give a (correct) answer to your question but I suggest that you modify it to make more clear that you don't understand why `const B b{A(2)};` doesn't compile and `const BOK bok{A(2)};` compile. Maybe because I don't understand English very well but it's seems to me that this point isn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look solely the declaration of `B`'s constructor:

```cpp
constexpr B::B(A a_);
```

The compiler knows that this can not possibly be `constexpr`, since it would have to copy the non-literal type `A`.

If you look at `BOK`'s constructor:

```cpp
constexpr BOK::BOK(const A& a_);
```

This *could* be called in a constant expression (Like `extern A value; BOK{value}`), if you don't look at the actual definition.

[Until C++23](https://wg21.link/P2448R2), it is "ill-formed, no diagnostic required" if there is no way to call a constexpr function or constructor in a constant expression. `constexpr B::B(A a_)` can be ruled out fast, and that's all that GCC is willing to check (it's a trade off for slower compile times vs more correctness). Your `BOK` struct's constructor is also ill-formed, but the compiler just isn't warning you.

As a side note, you can make `A` a literal type with *any* constexpr constructor:

```cpp
#include <bit>

struct A
{
    A(int a_)
    :m_a{a_}
    {
    }

    int m_a;

    constexpr A() = delete;  // Now a literal type
};

struct B
{
    constexpr B(A a_)
    :m_a{a_}
    {
    }
    A m_a;
};

struct BOK
{
    constexpr BOK(const A& a_)
    :m_a{a_}
    {
    }

    A m_a;
};

constexpr A a{std::bit_cast<A>(2)};
constexpr B b{std::bit_cast<A>(2)};
constexpr BOK bok{std::bit_cast<A>(2)};
```

Comment: The link you provided is not working, could you please update it?